# How Do I Process on The Image That Have Been Uploaded By The User?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm currently learning HTML5 along with JavaScript. I have coding like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Drop images and invert them</title> 
<style> 
body { margin: 0; body: 0; } 
canvas { margin: 30px auto 0; display: block; }
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'), 
    img = document.createElement('img'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
function xray() {
  img.src = 'a1.jpg';
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var pixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < pixels.data.length; i += 4) {
    pixels.data[i+0] = 255 - pixels.data[i+0];
    pixels.data[i+1] = 255 - pixels.data[i+2];
    pixels.data[i+2] = 255 - pixels.data[i+1];
  }
  ctx.putImageData(pixels, 0, 0);
};

</script> 
<form onclick="xray()" method="post">
Select a file:<br>
<input type="file" id="test" size="40">
</p>
<div>
<input type="button" value="View XRay">
</div>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

(which is an example taken from my book).

Actually, in this example, the image that is given to the script is `a1.jpg`(in our case) and when the user clicks the button, the `a1.jpg` file will be inverted in pixels and then be rendered.

What I'm currently doing is that I give a file upload option for the user, where he/she can upload a .jpg file.

Now what I want is, that the file which has been uploaded by the user, should be processed, i.e rather than `a1.jpg` I need to process the user-specified one.

Now my question is how can I do that? Is that possible? I'm very new to JavaScript, so it will be good if the community helps me.

Comment: Perhaps you should do this serverside, process it after it has been uploaded on the server.

Comment: oh I thought so, so there is no way of doing this in client side?

Comment: I really, really doubt it. File upload is heavily secured, you cant do anything with it for obvious security issues. You could perhaps alternatively upload it via ajax or something, that would work.

Comment: Yup: “upload” means “send a file to a server”. There is work ongoing on a File API (see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications), so there might be some browser-specific JavaScript you can use to process files locally in some browsers, but I don’t think it’s widespread yet.

Comment: Although according to caniuse.com, [Firefox, Chrome and Opera](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) have some support for reading local files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FileReader` to read the file as DataURL, apply it to an `<img>` element, and then use the img element as you are already using. It is described here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files

Here is the code that I wrote, based on the above mentioned tutorial:

```
function _reader_load_finished(ev) {
    var img_input = document.getElementById('img_input');
    img_input.setAttribute('src', ev.target.result);
    // Rest of your code here.
    // Probably you need to add code only after the image has loaded,
    // i.e., after <img> onload event.
}

function process_image(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', _reader_load_finished, false);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function file_change_handler(ev) {
    if (ev.target.files.length >= 1) {
        process_image(ev.target.files[0]);
    }
}

function dragover_handler(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
}

function drop_handler(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    ev.preventDefault();

    if (ev.dataTransfer.files.length >= 1) {
        process_image(ev.dataTransfer.files[0]);
    }
}

function onload_handler(ev) {
    var input_file = document.getElementById('input_file');
    input_file.addEventListener('change', file_change_handler, false);
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('dragover', dragover_handler, false);
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('drop', drop_handler, false);
}

window.addEventListener('load', onload_handler, false);
```